# unable to update ubuntu 16.1

Tags: updates

> Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them,
>   since they are a common source of problems. Furthermore run the
>   following command in a Terminal: `apt-get install -f`

When i try to update ,I get the error above.I am on Ubuntu 16.1

Comment: 1. Edit your post with proper formatting
2. Have you tried apt-get install -f ?

Answer (score 0):

Something went wrong and it's most likely because some non-Ubuntu repository are your system.
Run the following commands in your terminal,click `Ctrl+Alt+T` to start it the paste the following commands

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Else edit your sources.list manual and comment out or delete any repo you think might be causing problems.use gedit or nano any test editor like `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`